# saving figures using plt.savefig on colaboratory

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I am using collaboratory(online jupyter notebook) 
I have the following code i am plotting some graphs using this functions and want to save plots locally 
how can I do this ?

```
def make_plot_comparison(Xlabel,Ylabel,l1,l2,l1_title,l2_title,name): 
    plt.xlabel(Xlabel)
    plt.ylabel(Ylabel)
    plt.plot(l1,label=l1_title)
    plt.plot(l2,label=l2_title)
    plt.legend(loc='center right')
    plt.title(name)
    #plt.xlim(-5, 25)
    plt.savefig("abc.png")
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Right mousebutton, "save image as..." ?

Comment: yes it works but I want to do it by code ! because I  am plotting so many graphs so it would not be possible to right click and save all !

Comment: open('filetosavein.img', 'w') and then write into the file

Comment: If that "online jupyter notebook" is run on a server, I doubt you can run any code that saves the images somewhere, other than on that server. It should however be possible to download the complete notebook.

Comment: write function only work with strings isn't it ?

Comment: yes @ImportanceOfBeingErnest but I can not run it on my machine that is why i am using it on server !

Comment: I guess it should be possible to extract the images from the downloaded notebook, possibly using nbconvert as in chapter 3 of [this guide](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/nbconvert/latest/nbconvert.pdf).

Comment: I have the same issue. I want to save the file _on the google drive_. This way I can work with collaborators. @monamona, Even if I do this, python does not complain, but the file does not show up anywhere on my Google drive. I used the solution below, but it seems stupid to download a file locally, then have to upload it to get it back on Google drive. For one thing, that can't be automated.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

maybe it can save the picture independently

```
from google.colab import files
plt.savefig("abc.png")
files.download("abc.png")
```

https://colab.research.google.com/notebook#fileId=/v2/external/notebooks/io.ipynb&scrollTo=p2E4EKhCWEC5

Answer (score 11):

As mentioned in another answer, the `files.download` function is the perfect solution if you want to create the image file and download it on the fly. But what if you do not actually need to download the file, but you simply want to store the image to a directory in your Google Drive account? Maybe you are generating tons of such files (e.g. intermediate results during a time-consuming machine learning job) and you just can't download each file one by one.

In that case the solution I employed might be of help for you too. First of all, let's mount our Google Drive on our runtime.

```
# mount drive
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
```

**Note**: you can do that at the beginning of your notebook and then forget about it for the entire session, no need to do that for each image of course!

With the Google Drive mounted, you can now store your image files (or any other file you wish, for that matter) in any directory of your choice in Drive, e.g.:

```
images_dir = '/content/gdrive/My Drive/Images'
plt.savefig(f"{images_dir}/abc.png")
```

Comment: The saved image files in G Drive turned out to be blank files. Any clue what could have caused that?

Comment: It is difficult to say without further details, but usually these kind of problems are related to permission issues. Are you sure you have the permission to write to the folder you are trying to store the files to?

Answer (score 1):

Graph with seaborn export from google colab

```
plt.figure(figsize=(8,5))
ax = sns.stripplot(x='colname', y='colname', data=database)
ax.set_xlabel('') # this line hide/remove the label in x axis
ax.set_ylabal('label')
plt.savefig('name.png')
files.download('name.png') # this line opens your documents in your pc to save your png
```

Answer (score 1):

```
plt.savefig('/content/gdrive/MyDrive/tesis/imagenes/50prc_trabajo.png',bbox_inches='tight')
files.download("/content/gdrive/MyDrive/tesis/imagenes/50prc_trabajo.png")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   plt.savefig('/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/res_data/dimers/'+str(yname)+'_'+str(xname)+'_'+str(dimername), bbox_inches='tight' )
                
    you can save as :                
          
    /content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/res_data/dimers/zeta_beta_GA.png
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're working on the google collab and needs to download the png file of any plot use this code below:

```py
images_dir = '/content/gdrive/My Drive/Images'

plt.savefig(f"{images_dir}/abc.png")
```