# How to share your output image from google colab to google drive and downloading?

Tags: opencv, matplotlib, google-colaboratory

> i have tried different answers. but no success.[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48541040/saving-figures-using-plt-savefig-on-colaboratory)

```
plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
fig = plt.gcf()
output_image = 
predict_on_crops(saved_model,'/content/drive/MyDrive/crack_img_f/de65bfc4563c4813bb25bb65eb6cfe76.jpg', 128, 128,)
plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(output_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
plt.show()
```

> I am downloading the plt it is showing blank image.

```
from google.colab import files
plt.savefig("abc.png")
files.download("abc.png")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
!pip install -U -q PyDrive
```

```
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
from google.colab import auth
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
```

```
auth.authenticate_user()
gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)
uploaded = drive.CreateFile({'title': 'abc.png'})
uploaded.SetContentFile('abc.png')
uploaded.Upload()
print('Uploaded file with ID {}'.format(uploaded.get('id')))
```

Comment: i read your answer which is quite accurate, but i have another question if you can answer it?, what if i have more than one Text columns in the dataframe, how can we tokenize and pad_sequences those columns and reassign them to the Dataframe again. Here is my question posted,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67769093/after-tokenize-a-column-of-text-how-to-reassigned-that-tokenized-output-which